# Зашифровать ссылку в base64

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Хотелось бы как то закодировать ссылку на пост в base64 slug:slug. Желательно без вмешательства в БД, а уже поверх SlugField, если такое возможно.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<slug:slug>', post, name='post-detail'),
]
```

```
def post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'post': post
    }
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

Comment: `'slug': base64.b64encode(self.slug)` и `slug=base64.b64decode(slug)` и это не шифрование

Comment: @andreymal Знаю, что это не совсем шифрование, просто нужно привести ссылку к такому виду, я попробовал вставить ваши значения, не реагирует он на такую ссылку.

Comment: А зачем Вам вообще это нужно? Может, подойдёт [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify)?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Я читал про slugify, но зачем усложнять, если здесь slug уже работает, нужно лишь конвертировать ссылку в Base64. Например сейчас /post/title1 а надо /post/dGl0bGUx использовав base64.b64encode